# Reading AC signal from a XBee analog input pin

Tags: arduino, ac, dc, current-measurement, xbee

I'm trying to use a [ACS756SCA-100B](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS756-Datasheet.ashx) - 100A Hall Effect-Based Linear Current Sensor IC (SCT-013-030) with a precision of 20 mV/A.

My objective is to read input voltage coming from the sensor into the XBee Analog input.

I was wondering if that would be possible by making precision half-wave rectifier, to rectify the sensor output into the XBee. I know that even with half-wave I still get a variation, so I guess that's far from perfect...

On the other hand I've seen these type of projects working with arduino, but as far as I understood, it will basically sample the AC wave a number of times and applies the RMS on it afterwards.

Is it possible to use XBee directly or must I process the wave first on a microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

The analog pins on an Xbee act virtually identically to the analog pins on an Arduino -- they are inputs to a [successive approximation analog-to-digital converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_Approximation_ADC). If the ADC performance of the Xbee is sufficient for your application, then you don't need an additional microcontroller (check the Xbee datasheet for this). And yes, you should use a half-wave rectifier or some other means of protecting your input pins, since the current sensor you mention can output negative voltage.

Comment: So, I had some suspicions in what the XBee sampling rate is regarded but I went to check it anyway. And as far as I could get from the XBee specifications, you can specify the sample rate in milliseconds, and this sample is sent out through a sampling API frame. So, basically I would have to set a high sampling rate, receive the samples on the controller and process it. 
The advantage of using a ATmega or ATTiny MC is that I could do whatever calculations on the MC and send the result through the XBee. Correct me if I am wrong...